# Running AWS CloudWatch logs agent on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Has anybody successfully run the AWS CloudWatch Logs Agent on a Raspberry Pi 4?

When I run the script below, it appears to work, but the awslogs.service does not get created.

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com//aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O
```

I suspect it simply isn't compatible, so I what to see if anybody else had success. Any other suggestions for centralized logging for a Raspberry Pi cluster?

Comment: have you tried installing CloudWatch Unified agent? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/installing-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html

Comment: I tried to install the CloudWatch agent. The installation completes without error, but the agent service does not get created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937004/running-aws-cloudwatch-logs-agent-on-raspberry-pi-4

Comment: Also, I only see Debian AMD64 on the download page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html

Comment: Seem to not be officially supported at least. The only thing I found that almost did work was a plugin to the collectd service (https://ownthe.cloud/posts/configure-aws-cloudwatch-plugin/). Unfortunately that installation did not work because it is written for python 2.X but Raspberry PI 4 only has Python3 installed. Seems these tools are very close to get up and running on Raspberry PI, but the installation currently isn't trivial

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-imaging my Raspberry Pi 4 with the 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS, at which point I was able to follow the instructions to download and install the .deb file for ARM64 Ubuntu on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html.

```
cd /opt
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/ubuntu/arm64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
sudo dpkg -i -E ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
```